# C# Windows phone 8 Recursively Read SocketStream [OutOfmemory]

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, windows-phone-8, c#-5.0

I am reading data recursively from streamsockets in Windows phone 8. It works perfect but there is memory leak. I.e. the memory sizes increase after each read. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this? Here is my implementation

```
public async Task ReadSocket(StreamSocket Socket)
{            
    try
    {
        uint intBytesRead;
        var dataReader = new DataReader(Socket.InputStream);
        dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        intBytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(4);                
        if (intBytesRead == 0)
        {
            OnDisconnect(Socket);
            return;
        }

        while (intBytesRead < 4)
        {
            uint read = await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)4 - intBytesRead);
            if (read == 0)
            {
                OnDisconnect(Socket);
                return;
            }
            intBytesRead += read;
        }

        byte[] data = new byte[4];
        dataReader.ReadBytes(data);

        int lenHTN = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);

        int length = CommonUtil.ConvertNToH(lenHTN);                

        if (length < 1)
        {
            OnDisconnect(Socket);
            return;
        }

        data = new byte[length];

        uint dataBytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)length);                

        if (dataBytesRead == 0)
        {
            OnDisconnect(Socket);
            return;
        }

        while (dataBytesRead < length)
        {
            uint read = await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)length - dataBytesRead);
            if (read == 0)
            {
                OnDisconnect(Socket);
                return;
            }
            dataBytesRead += read;
        }

        dataReader.ReadBytes(data);

        Debug.WriteLine("Check Memory Status");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        if (SocketError.GetStatus(ex.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.ConnectionResetByPeer)
        {
            OnDisconnect(Socket);
            return;
        }
    }          
await ReadSocket(Socket);
```

}

and here is the output

```
Check Memory Status
```

Current: 25MB   Limit: 314MB
Check Memory Status
Current: 25MB   Limit: 314MB
Check Memory Status
Current: 25MB   Limit: 314MB
Check Memory Status
Current: 25MB   Limit: 314MB
Check Memory Status
Current: 26MB   Limit: 314MB
Check Memory Status
Current: 26MB   Limit: 314MB
Check Memory Status
Current: 27MB   Limit: 314MB
Check Memory Status
Current: 27MB   Limit: 314MB
Check Memory Status
Current: 27MB   Limit: 314MB
.
.
.
Check Memory Status
Current: 72MB   Limit: 314MB
Check Memory Status
Current: 72MB   Limit: 314MB
.
.
It continues till the application crash because of OutOfmemory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory leak is caused is caused by the recursion. When it comes to memory, `async` methods behave almost the same as normal synchronous methods, except that their local variables are stored on the heap.

So, with your code, the memory for `data`, other variables from the method and some additional information (like the `Task` that's returned from the method) from previous iterations are never released, which is causing your leak.

If you added `data = null;` before the recursive `await`, that would likely improve the situation significantly, but it wouldn't fix the leak.

For that, you would need to change your code from recursive to a normal loop. Something like:

```
bool finished = false;
while (!finished)
{
    finished = await ReadSingleSocket(socket);
}
```

Where `ReadSingleSocket()` is a method that contains most of the code from your `ReadSocket()`, except the recursive `await`. It will return `true` when reading should stop and `false` otherwise.

Comment: You are right.. I have modified my method. Now its working fine. Thanks for the tip :)